# Configurable product select from attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have `configurable_product`'s `id` and `color`=`red` and `size`=`x`
How can I get that product current stock in programmatically.
Their inventory is:

`------------------------------------------------------------
     | Name                        | id |  Stock           |
     -------------------------------------------------------
     | configurable_product        |  6 |  0(not visible)  |
     -------------------------------------------------------
     | configurable_product_red_X  |  7 |  1               |
     -------------------------------------------------------
     | configurable_product_red_l  |  8 |  5               |
     -------------------------------------------------------
     | configurable_product_blue_s |  9 |  0               |
     -------------------------------------------------------
     | configurable_product_blue_x | 10 |  2               |
     -------------------------------------------------------`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento configurable products ***does not have it own stock***.It stock is **totally depends on it child's product stocks**.

If you want ***a particular products variance  (color=red and size=x) stock*** then first check which child product have those two option (color=red and size=x)  and after that  get that child product and  by child  product inventory module,you will  get ur desire  result

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->loadByProduct($_Childproduct);
```

### You can try this:

```
<?php
/* Get Child Product ids from  parent product ids */

$ids=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->getChildrenIds($_ParentId);
/* Create Custom product collection which is filter by Child Product ids */         
 $_subproducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addIdFilter($ids)->addFieldToSelect('name');
/* add another  filter by color =red, size=x
@ assume that  red option id is 10;
@also assume that  x option is 52

*/  
$_subproducts->addFieldToFilter('color',10)->ddFieldToFilter('size',52);
        foreach ( $_subproducts  as $simple) {
                $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple);
                print_r($stock);

        }
?>
```